# International to US Domestic transfer baggage fees

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage

I'm aware of this question and answers to it.

[Baggage allowance of separate domestic flights with a connecting international flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9747/baggage-allowance-of-separate-domestic-flights-with-a-connecting-international-f)

My question is more specific. My wife has a flight to LAX (on Emirates). I want to get her another flight to San Francisco. Note that the domestic flight is being bought separately. What are the options for not paying baggage fees other than flying Southwest? She will have 2 checked bags.

Comment: So basically you just want a flight from LAX to SFO without baggage fees, correct? It won't matter that she's come from overseas if it's bought separately, would it?

Comment: If the airlines price is too high, let her take one with her and ship the other through FedEx ground. It will be much cheaper and won't take longer. Perhaps the airport has a FedEx ground office.

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d32137!2d-118.3693017!3d33.9359377!4m25!2m11!1m10!1s0x0%3A0x967611d54e301964!3m8!1m3!1d26081603!2d-95.677068!3d37.0625!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5m12!1m11!1sfedex+ground+in+LAX!4m8!1m3!1d26081603!2d-95.677068!3d37.0625!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!17b1

Comment: @MarkMayo I have heard it might be possible to check bags for free when transferring from international flight to us domestic flight, even if tickets are purchased separately. I read it somewhere that someone has done it!

Answer (score 3):

You could consider [JetBlue](http://www.jetblue.com/) - their tickets include one free checked bag.  However they don't have direct flights to San Francisco, so the savings in luggage are probably more easily offset by buying a direct flight, frankly :/

Also, depending on the terms of her ticket, and if you used a travel agent, you may be able to amend the original ticket to go to San Francisco.  This way it'd all be on the same ticket (handy in the event of problems) and you may be able to get the baggage allowance included.  It may not be on the same airline, but code-shared with one of their partners, if they have any that fly up there.

Comment: For such an amendment, it will be worth calling the airline. The travel agents may be able to identify code shares that may not be obvious via their internet site. In general, if your ticket includes an overseas leg, the overseas baggage allowance overrules the domestic one.