# Which carry-on rules apply on a domestic leg of an international flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage

If you have both a domestic and an international (e.g. transatlantic) leg on your flight, checked luggage allowances are [determined by the international leg](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9747/baggage-allowance-of-separate-domestic-flights-with-a-connecting-international-f).

Recently, some US domestic carrier have made [stricter rules for carry-on luggage](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/columnist/hobica/2014/06/10/carry-on-luggage-bag-size-limits/10246511/) on domestic flights by limiting the size of the bags (especially width). Do similar rules apply for carry-on luggage as for checked luggage, i.e. could you get around these restrictions on the domestic leg if you have a connecting international leg, or would you need to check-in your carry-on on the domestic leg of the flight?

Comment: I would comply with the domestic flight to be honest. In case of check-in it's a matter of regulation. In case of domestic flights, it's genuinely possible that the plane is small and cannot support a larger carry on. I have found it difficult to store my 17 inch laptop bag in the overhead bins and have almost always had issues while stowing it underneath the seat.

Comment: This'll depend on the airline, sometimes.  And especially if you have the same / different airlines for the two legs.

Answer (score 3):

In theory you're [supposed to be told what applies at ticketing](http://www.atpco.net/atpco/download/Five_baggage_facts.pdf):

> Airlines and travel agents must also specify at the time of ticketing the carry-on allowance and/or charges

In practice it would not surprise me to find that that does not include actual dimensions as the airlines like to retain the ability to change these without warning, as per [your linked article](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/columnist/hobica/2014/06/10/carry-on-luggage-bag-size-limits/10246511/).

If the actual dimensions are not specified (only the number and/or charges) I would suggest adhering to the more restrictive of the flights to avoid unnecessary hassle at the airport because you don't have a fallback position of showing your baggage dimensions in writing, only your allowance.